# React Native assets placement

Tags: android, ios, react-native

What is the best solution for React Native? Image files together with js files or as resources with various resolitions (res dir on Android)?

Answer (score 1):

I think from an organizational standpoint it's best to have them together with the source code, i.e. the js files and then using `require('image/name.png')` to include them.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you